# Cómo filtra por usuario en Node JS y MongoDB

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Me encuentro elaborando una aplicación con Node JS y MongoDB como base de datos. Las colecciones que manejo son usuarios y agendas.

Estoy usando aggregate para poder obtener el total de los gastos del usuario , de la siguiente forma:

```
agendaRoutes.get('/info',[verificaToken], async (req: any, res: Response) => {

  const id = req.usuario._id;
  const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

  var pipeline = [

                    {
                        "$match": { estado: "finalizado" }
                    },
                   
                     { 
                          "$unwind": "$servicio.monto"
                      }, 
                    
                      {
                         "$group":
                                    { "_id":"$usuario" ,
                                       "total": { "$sum": "$servicio.monto" },
                                       "monto": { "$push": "$servicio.monto" }
                                    }
                      },
                      {"$match": { _id: ObjectId(id)}}
               ] 

                     
           Agenda.aggregate(pipeline) .exec(function(err, results) 
                      { if (err) throw err; 
                        
                        if( results.length === 0 ) {
                          return res.json({
                            ok:false,
                            mensaje: 'No posee ningun registro'
                          });
                        }
                        
                          res.json({
                            ok: true,
                            results,
                          });
                    })

  });
```

[image]

[image: Resultado del postman]

Me gustaría saber como poder filtrar por usuario logeado, ya que la siguiente función no me funciona

```
  {"$match": { _id: id }},
```

[image: Base de Datos de la colección agenda]

Comment: Hola. Actualiza tu pregunta por favor y pon tu codigo. Es más fácil que te respondan de esa manera.

Comment: El código en formato texto, por favor. En imágenes no se puede *copiar y pegar* para intentar reproducir el problema. No todos estamos dispuestos a re escribir todo el código de la imagen. Saludos

Comment: El título no se actualiza. Marca la respuesta correcta como Aceptada (o pon tu solución y la marcas un rato después como aceptada. Ese chulito verde es la señal de que se encontró solución a tu pregunta. De paso, procura seguir las recomendaciones que te hacen en los comentarios, Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El primer stage `$match` no te funciona por que estas comparando un `ObjectId()` con un `String`. Para lograr el resultado deseado debes convertir tu `String` a un `ObjectId()` de la siguiente manera:

```
{"$match": { _id: ObjectId(id)}}
```

Importando asi :

```
const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, ya me funciona perfecto  !

Comment: @Vane marca la respuesta como aceptada. Selecciona el tick a la izquierda de la respuesta para que quede de color verde.